# Becoming a permanent resident of Canada with a remote US job

Tags: canada

My SO and I have decided to get married and we have looking to settle down in Canada. She is a Canadian citizen and is able to sponsor my residency. I am a US Citizen. We are choosing Canada since her career is tied to the Canadian government.

My concerns are around finding work in Canada. An Uncle and a family friend really struggled to find employment in Canada as highly educated immigrants. They were severely underemployed for a number of years until they built up a Canadian network. They both held graduate degrees from Top 50 institutions in the US. One was a trained physician and the other was a mechanical engineer.

My plan to overcome the above is to take advantage of remote work opportunities at my current employer and work remotely from Canada. And network with Canadian tech scene while employed remotely. I have experience working as a data scientist and software engineer.

My questions are:

- Is it acceptable to work remotely for a US company from Canada?
- Is this looked upon favorably when applying for residency?
- Let's say I unexpectedly lose the job at some point. Is remote work looked upon favorably in Canada? Would it be perceived as "Canadian work experience" if I've been a resident for a few years at that point?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as my experience is only related to software gigs but in short yes, a lot of people work remotely for american companies and get paid in USD. Also remote work is most definitely considered an experience. I know a lot of people doing similar remote jobs for US companies. A lot of Canadian companies are also moving to a permanent WFH environment (Shopify comes to mind). So if anything, its considered an advantage to get paid in USD as Canadian dollar is weaker.